# Change internal domain controller in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Been searching for this, and if i recall it's a simple command but i can't for the life of me remember it.

My problem:
I'm visiting a different office in my company and the domain controller i'm connected to here can't find any forests in the domain to search user accounts for Skype for Business.

How can i change to a different domain controller in the same domain?  Like changing from This-DC1 to Main-DC1?

Comment: Is this a question about code? If so, please include the code, ideally a [mcve]. Please read [ask].

Comment: `nltest /server:main-dc1.fqdn /sc_reset:domain\main-dc1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discover a domain controller this command will do it:

```
(Get-ADDomainController -Discover).name
```